# Using OpenSSL EVP. How to Encrypt a string and save the Encrypted string, key and IV to a file? Then Open the file and Decrypt back to string?

Tags: c++, openssl, wxwidgets

Hi All I have been struggling for a few days now and can't figure this out. I'm new to C++ and I'm trying to encrypt a string. Then Save the encrypted string, key and IV to a file.

The encryption works, I generate a Key and IV. Then Continue to encrypt the string.
I then want to save the data to a file as follows.

I want to save the encrypted string on the first line of the file, the Key on the second line and the IV on the third line.

I'm struggling to save the data correctly.

From there, I would like to read the file. Set the first line as the string to decrypt, Second line as the Key and Third to use as the IV.

I think the issue I have is the correct way to save / write the data to a file and read the data back to decrypt the data.

Can someone help me to find the right direction.

Here Is what i have Got so far:

encryption.h

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <openssl/aes.h>
#include <openssl/rand.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;



class Encryption {

    public:

    static std::string encodeText(const std::string &rawText, uint8_t key, uint8_t ivs)
    {
        uint8_t Keyt[32] = { key };
        uint8_t IV[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = { ivs }; // Generate an AES Key

        // Make a copy of the IV to IVd as it seems to get destroyed when used
        uint8_t IVd[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < AES_BLOCK_SIZE; i++) {
            IVd[i] = IV[i];
        }

        /** Setup the AES Key structure required for use in the OpenSSL APIs **/
        AES_KEY* AesKey = new AES_KEY();
        AES_set_encrypt_key(Keyt, 256, AesKey);

        /** take an input string and pad it so it fits into 16 bytes (AES Block Size) **/
        const int UserDataSize = (const int)rawText.length();   // Get the length pre-padding
        int RequiredPadding = (AES_BLOCK_SIZE - (rawText.length() % AES_BLOCK_SIZE));   // Calculate required padding
        std::vector<unsigned char> PaddedTxt(rawText.begin(), rawText.end());   // Easier to Pad as a vector
        for (int i = 0; i < RequiredPadding; i++) {
            PaddedTxt.push_back(0); //  Increase the size of the string by
        }                           //  how much padding is necessary

        unsigned char* UserData = &PaddedTxt[0];// Get the padded text as an unsigned char array
        const int UserDataSizePadded = (const int)PaddedTxt.size();// and the length (OpenSSl is a C-API)

        /** Peform the encryption **/
        unsigned char EncryptedData[512] = { 0 }; // Hard-coded Array for OpenSSL (C++ can't dynamic arrays)
        AES_cbc_encrypt(UserData, EncryptedData, UserDataSizePadded, (const AES_KEY*)AesKey, IV, AES_ENCRYPT);

        string en = hex_print(EncryptedData, sizeof(EncryptedData));
        //string en = toIntStingFromChar(enh, sizeof(enh));

        return en;
    }

    static std::string decodeText(const std::string& rawText, uint8_t key, uint8_t ivs)
    {
        uint8_t Keyt[32] = {key};
        uint8_t IV[AES_BLOCK_SIZE] = {ivs}; // Generate an AES Key

        // Make a copy of the IV to IVd as it seems to get destroyed when used
        uint8_t IVd[AES_BLOCK_SIZE];
        for (int i = 0; i < AES_BLOCK_SIZE; i++) {
            IVd[i] = IV[i];
        }

        /** take an input string and pad it so it fits into 16 bytes (AES Block Size) **/
        const int UserDataSize = (const int)rawText.length();   // Get the length pre-padding
        int RequiredPadding = (AES_BLOCK_SIZE - (rawText.length() % AES_BLOCK_SIZE));   // Calculate required padding
        std::vector<unsigned char> PaddedTxt(rawText.begin(), rawText.end());   // Easier to Pad as a vector

        unsigned char* UserData = &PaddedTxt[0];// Get the padded text as an unsigned char array
        const int UserDataSizePadded = (const int)PaddedTxt.size();// and the length (OpenSSl is a C-API)

        /** Setup an AES Key structure for the decrypt operation **/
        AES_KEY* AesDecryptKey = new AES_KEY(); // AES Key to be used for Decryption
        AES_set_decrypt_key(Keyt, 256, AesDecryptKey);   // We Initialize this so we can use the OpenSSL Encryption API

        /** Decrypt the data. Note that we use the same function call. Only change is the last parameter **/
        unsigned char DecryptedData[512] = { 0 }; // Hard-coded as C++ doesn't allow for dynamic arrays and OpenSSL requires an array
        AES_cbc_encrypt(UserData, DecryptedData, UserDataSizePadded, (const AES_KEY*)AesDecryptKey, IVd, AES_DECRYPT);

        string de = hex_print(DecryptedData, sizeof(DecryptedData)-1);

        return de;
    }

    // Convert Hex to string
    static std::string hex_print(const void* pv, size_t len)
    {
        std::string r;
        const unsigned char* p = (const unsigned char*)pv;
        if (NULL == pv)
            r = "null";
        else
        {
            size_t i = 0;
            for (i; i < len; ++i)
                r += ("%02X ", *p++);
        }
        return r;
    }

    // Generate a Key
    static unsigned char *generateKey(unsigned char *buf, size_t length) {
        
        if (!RAND_bytes(buf, length)) {
            return NULL;
        }
        return buf;
    }

    // Generate a IV
    static unsigned char* generateIv(unsigned char* buf, size_t length) {

        if (!RAND_bytes(buf, length)) {
            return NULL;
        }
        return buf;
    }

    // Convert int to string
    static std::string toIntSting(uint8_t Keyt[], int length) {
        
        std::string k;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            k += std::to_string(Keyt[i]);
        } 
        wxString s(k);
        wxLogDebug(s);
        return k;
    }

    // Convert int to string from a Char
    static std::string toIntStingFromChar(unsigned char* test, int length) {

        std::string k;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            k += std::to_string(test[i]);
        }
        wxString s(k);
        wxLogDebug(s);
        return k;
    }

    // Write the data to a file
    static void writeToFile(std::string text, std::string Keyt, std::string IV) {
        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("example.txt");
        myfile << text;
        myfile << "\n";
        myfile << Keyt;
        myfile << "\n";
        myfile << IV;
        myfile.close();
    }

    // Open the file With the encrypted data
    static std::string* OpenFile() {

        static string myArray[3];

        ifstream myfile("example.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            {
                // line 1 = text to decrypt
                // line 2 = key
                // line 3 = IV
                myfile >> myArray[i];
            }
            myfile.close();
        }

        return myArray;
    }
};
```

I'm using it as follows

```
// Encrpyt
    uint8_t Keyt[32];
    uint8_t IV[AES_BLOCK_SIZE]; 
    // Generate an AES Key, IV
    Encryption::generateKey(Keyt, sizeof(Keyt));
    Encryption::generateKey(IV, sizeof(IV));

    // Convert the Key to a string for saving to a file
    wxString p = Encryption::toIntSting(Keyt, sizeof(Keyt));
    wxLogDebug(p);

    // Convert the IV to a string for saving to a file
    wxString i = Encryption::toIntSting(IV, sizeof(IV));
    wxLogDebug(i);

    // Encrypt the string
    string response = Encryption::encodeText("password to encrypt", *Keyt, *IV);
    wxString r(response);

    // Save / write to a file
    Encryption::writeToFile(r.ToStdString(), p.ToStdString(), i.ToStdString());


    // Decrypt
    // Open File and return
    // line 1 = text to decrypt
    // line 2 = key
    // line 3 = IV
    string data[3] = { *Encryption::OpenFile() };    
    
    unsigned char key[32] = { (unsigned char)data[1].c_str() };
    unsigned char ivss[32] = { (unsigned char)data[2].c_str() };

   string de = Encryption::decodeText(data[0].c_str(), *key, *ivss);

    wxString d = de;
    wxLogDebug(d);
```

When it writes to a file I get Something as follows:
example.txt

```
b‡f‡2É>ƒ}ã[Å8kH° [¥%WÔù¡dÃy ¼                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
17892143551869940267171785144164159149238210130121845322513358186346341616556
246140155172213011360214244852359123919
```

Some times the encrypted text (first line) will take up two lines which already is incorrect.
My heads all over the place and i can't even figure out how to continue / look towards any more. All examples I found on overflow and on other Blogs etc only print the data to screen put not on how to save the data to a file.

Thank you.

All I want to do is encrypt a string. Then Save the encrypted string, key and IV to a file. Then Open the file and decrypt the data.

Comment: the easiest solution is not to save the strings to a file. Or not to save it into the text file. Save into the (SQLite) db. Save it into the binary file. When you encrypt the data sometimes in the resulting string there will be a symbol `\n` (carriage return) which will be represented as new line and threfore the encrypted string will be represented with 2 lines. But the file you are saving is a text file.

Comment: Thank you Igor. How do I go about saving to a binary file? I want to encrypt data such as Sql connection password etc to I file. So that when the application starts up, it will decrypt the Sql user, pass, host etc and then continue to  use the data.

Comment: @Igor How does saving it in a text file or sqlite db or *any* other type of file, actually *matter*? It's the same data being saved in any case. The format of the file doesn't actually change anything. OP just wants to save his data to *any* file.

Comment: "Save the encrypted string, key and IV to a file" - Note that if you save the cipher text, key and IV to the same file, then anyone who gets hold of that file can trivially decrypt your string - you've saved *all* information needed to do so in the same place. Doesn't sound like a very good idea.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Thank you. Yes I'm planning on having the user enter in a password. Which will be used to encrypt the "key" saved in the file. So the Key will be decrypted first with the users password, then the application will use that to decrypt the data again. If that makes sense. As soon as I'm able to get the saving part working. What gets saved and where will come afterwards.

Comment: @JonoM just don't invent your own crypto or crypto storage scheme, please. Unless you are a cryptography expert (in which case I don't think you'd be asking here), that rarely goes well.

Comment: @JesperJuhl No not at all, That's why I'm using OpenSSL EVP. I am by far not an expert ;)

Answer (score 0):

To be able to read variable length binary data (as you seem to do in the first line) you need to write how much data you have to read for the first line, and the same for the following.

```
size data
```

Being `size` in binary (an `int` for example).

Then you read the length and the data in two steps.

```
char * buf;
file.read ((char*)&len, sizeof(int));
buf = new [len];
file.read (buf, len);
string = buf;
delete [] buf;
```

this for each line.

Take in account that binary data handled as strings may cause problems.